# Link my app to another app

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I'm just starting work on a new ChicagoBoss app (call it `my_app`). I've got an existing app (call it `ext_app`) I'd like to link to, so I can call functions such as `ext_app:start()` from `my_app`. At the moment I'm accomplishing this using `rebar`, which does work, but I'd rather do something along the lines of a shared library.

In `my_app/src/my_app.app.src` I've got the line:

```
{applications, [kernel, stdlib, crypto, boss]}
```

I'm envisioning that I would change that to:

```
{applications, [kernel, stdlib, crypto, boss, ext_app]}
```

But I don't know where to put the path to `ext_app`?

I suppose if I spent a week or three poring over the OTP documentation, I might figure it out, but . . . I guess I'd rather spend that time coding.

Oh, yeah - this is on a Debian "wheezy" system.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you just want to include the path to ext_app when starting your applications which would allow erlang to call ext_add:start().

Use flags -pa or -pz when starting erl to add a directory to the code path either in the beginning or the end. It's equivalent as using code:add_pathsa/1 or code:add_pathsz/1.